# Necessary and sufficient condition for projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let us have a $P$ module. We have to prove the following statement:

> $P$ is projective $\Leftrightarrow$ There is an $F$ free module, such that $F \cong F \oplus P$.

I have already seen the $\Rightarrow$ direction in a previously asked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63809/question-about-a-projective-module-in-a-direct-sum), but can't really think of anything to prove the other way.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If $F\cong F\oplus P$, then $P$ is a direct summand of a free module, which is one of the usual characterizations of a projective module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F\cong F\oplus P$, then $P$ is a direct summand of a free module, which is one of the usual characterizations of a projective module.

Comment: A *stupid* (!) question: if $F \cong F\oplus P$, how the ranks add up? Shouldn't it be "there exists a module $Q$ such that $Q\oplus P$ is a free module of finite rank"?

Comment: You should read to answer to the linked question in the OP. Also, there is no finite rank condition in the given characterization of projective.

Comment: Ah!! I see now. Thanks for clearing the confusion.

Comment: @Xam I had already done that.